# Java getElapsedTime in simple Stopwatch, returning the enum

Tags: java, enums, stopwatch

I made in Java a simple stopWatch for measuring time. One method of this class is:

```
public long[] getElapsedTime() {
        long timestamp;
        timestamp = (running) ? ((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) - (startTime / 1000)) : (((stopTime - startTime) / 1000));
        long day = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(timestamp);
        long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(timestamp) - (day * 24);
        long minutes = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(timestamp) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(timestamp) * 60);
        long seconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(timestamp) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(timestamp) * 60);
        return new long[] {day, hours, minutes, seconds};
    }
```

Method return a array with 4 members. But the calling of this method is so strange:

```
new Formatter().format("%02d:%02d:%02d", stopwatch.getElapsedTime()[1], stopwatch.getElapsedTime()[2], stopwatch.getElapsedTime()[3] ))
```

Can I make return this as some **"enum"** or something more human readable format? I imagine the implementation like this:

```
new Formatter().format("%02d:%02d:%02d", stopwatch.getElapsedTime().HOURS, stopwatch.getElapsedTime().MINUTES, stopwatch.getElapsedTime().SECONDS ))
```

It is possible?

I know that I can set elapsed time units in the class (class is not static) and then make **getters** for the units (e.g. *getDays()*, *getHours()*, *getMinutes()* and *getSeconds()*) But I think that this is not my imagine.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just create a `Time` class, and have `getElapsedTime()` return an instance of `Time` with the appropriate `getters` and `setters`?

Comment: Yes, good idea, thanks. But it's means next class. I think that keep whole stopwatch in one class is better and easier for future implementation. But thanks, you have my vote

Comment: I'd recommend not keeping every piece of the "stopwatch" in one class. Classes should be modular and describe one type of "thing". `Stopwatch` is a type of object, but `Time` is an attribute of a stopwatch, as are many other things.

Answer (score -1):

OMG I'm on a roll today for having great answers! I made some code that takes in the time in milliseconds and returns a String that is perfectly formatted to be drawn. Here it is:

```
public static String getTime(long time){
    long timeToEdit = time;
    String textToDraw = "";
    if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time) >= 10){
        textToDraw = textToDraw + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time);
    }else{
        textToDraw = textToDraw + "0" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time);
    }
    timeToEdit -=        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeToEdit));
    if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeToEdit) >= 10){
        textToDraw = textToDraw + ":" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeToEdit);
    }else{
        textToDraw = textToDraw + ":0" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeToEdit);
    }
    timeToEdit -= TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeToEdit));
    if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(timeToEdit) >= 100){
        textToDraw = textToDraw + ":" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(timeToEdit);
    }else if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(timeToEdit) >= 10) {
        textToDraw = textToDraw + ":0" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(timeToEdit);
    }else{
        textToDraw = textToDraw + ":00" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(timeToEdit);
    }
    return textToDraw;
}
```

For example, if you run:

```
System.out.println(getTime(60000));
```

will print

```
1:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want return strings in method. But thanks for idea